# Job Execution Listener is failed to store value in Job Execution Context Table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have implemented the function to store number of processed with failure and success into job execution context in afterJob() method of JobExecutionListener implemented:

```
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    final long jobExecutionId = jobExecution.getId();
    final BatchStatus jobStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
    final ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

    String exitCodeAndMessage = null;
    Map<String, Integer> recordsProcessed = null;

    switch (jobStatus) {
        case COMPLETED:
            //exitCodeAndMessage = getExitCodeAndMessageFromEveryStep(jobExecution);
            recordsProcessed = getExitCodeAndMessageFromEveryStep(jobExecution);
            if (exitCodeAndMessage == null) {
                exitCodeAndMessage = "COMPLETED";
            }
            jobExecutionContext.putString("AfterJob", "Success");
            jobExecutionContext.put("recordsProcessed", recordsProcessed);
            break;
```

After running the job, there is no value stored inside the table. Why?

Comment: None of the code you wrote writes information to the DB, and the JobExecution has already completed so Spring is not going to persist any changes you make to the context at this point.

Comment: How do I need to add code in order to write information to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

The job execution context is not saved after the job is finished but is saved in between every step execution. So you can use a `StepExecutionListener` and add these metrics in the `afterStep` method. More details on this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#executioncontext